# Possible proof of Leibniz Theorem

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

As a matter of fact, I had been reading integration for a while, and I came with a possible proof of Leibniz rule, which I am little unsure about.

Leibniz's Rule says :' If a $f(t)$ is a continuous function on intervals [a,b] and $α(x)$ and $β(x)$ are differnetiable functions of x whose values lie in [a,b] then;

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\beta(x)}^{\alpha(x)}f(t)dx=f(\alpha(x))\frac{d\alpha(x)}{dx}-f(β(x))\frac{dβ(x)}{dx}$$

Now proof:

(Note: I am denoting $\frac{dg(x)}{dx}$ as $g'(t)$)

Let indefinite integral of $f(t)$ be $g(t)+c$  $$\int f(t)dt=g(t)+c \rightarrow f(t)=g'(t)$$ 
Now putting $$t=\alpha(x) \rightarrow f(\alpha(x))=g'(\alpha(x))...(1)$$
$$t=\beta(x)\rightarrow f(\beta(x))=g'(\beta(x))...(2)$$
Now let's put limits on our indefinite integral
$$\int_{\beta(x)}^{\alpha(x)}f(t)dt=[g(t)+c]_{\beta(x)}^{\alpha(x)}=g(\alpha(x))-g(\beta(x))$$
Differentiating both sides $w.r.t$ $x$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\beta(x)}^{\alpha(x)}f(t)dt=g'(\alpha(x))\frac{d(\alpha(x)}{dx}-=g'(\beta(x))\frac{d(\beta(x)}{dx}$$
Hence we get finally $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\beta(x)}^{\alpha(x)}f(t)dx=f(\alpha(x))\frac{d\alpha(x)}{dx}-f(β(x))\frac{dβ(x)}{dx}$$
{From equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ I replaced $g'(\alpha(x))$ with $f(\alpha(x))$ and similarly for 2nd term}
Is this proof correct$?$ Please help and thanks in advance$!$ Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Great job man! Yes it's correct.